# vagrant doesn't map my laravel project folder created in local by composer in its folder

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have created my laravel project in /applications/mamp/htdocs/forms folder in local computer.
Then I have edited homestead.yaml file to set the folder and the site (picture 1)

Then I execute vagrant up but in the folder Code doesn't create the folder forms with my local project content.

Any idea please?

regards

[code folder in vahrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnl29.jpg)

[homestead.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYOZf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provision when you update the `.yaml`

run:

`vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: Eureka I was executing vagrant --provivion only with reload now works fine thanks